# Worklight 6.2 SSL configuration

Tags: ssl, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm trying to configure SSL on my local development machine so my adapters will be able to connect to the Bank-end service.

Our Back-end service team provided us with the following information:

1. ssl.keystore.path=conf/mobile.p12
2. ssl.keystore.type=PKCS12
3. ssl.keystore.password=PASSA
4. SSL ALias = AlIAS
5. SSL Password = PASSA

They send to use the "mobile.p12" file.

I added those configuration to my worklight.propeties:

```
#    Worklight SSL keystore 
#######################################################################################################################
ssl.keystore.path=conf/mobile.p12
#SSL certificate keystore type (jks or PKCS12)
ssl.keystore.type=PKCS12
#SSL certificate keystore password.
ssl.keystore.password= PASSA
```

In my Adapter.xml I added the following:

```
<sslCertificateAlias> AlIAS </sslCertificateAlias>
<sslCertificatePassword> PASSA </sslCertificatePassword>
```

When I deploy the project on my local Machine and try to login in the app through one of our adapters, I'm getting this error:

```
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0152E: Unable to find certificate chain with alias: 'AlIAS' [project MobileBanking]
```

I tried to import the certificate to the `default.keystore` inside server > config by:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore mobile.p12 -destkeystore default.keystore -srcstoretype PKCS12
```

the result is :

```
Import command completed:  0 entries successfully imported, 0 entries failed or cancelled
```

which indicated it didn't work since 0 entries.

after running the keytool command, the error changed when I click login in our application to be :

```
Http request failed: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
```

which indicated that my configuration is wrong.

What am I missing?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the type of your certificate (un-signed, self-signed, CA-issued), make sure you are following the instructions from: [Configuring Worklight Server](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/install_config/c_configuring_wl.html)

Specifically:

- http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/t_configuring_SSL_WL_adapters_backend_servers_certificates.html
- http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/c_ssl_config.html

Comment: Idan, apparently the issue is that when I build the project from "Project > build project" I'm getting this error "[ERROR   ] FWLSE0156E: HTTPS connections to backend servers will fail because SSL keystore file 'conf/mobile.p12' is not available. Change ssl.keystore.* properties in worklight.properties file to point to a SSL keystore. " even though the keystore is in the directory but it is not picking it up.